# why the command Diff2 is not working?

Tags: c#, .net, perforce

The command Diff2 is not giving the supposed output in `TaggedOutputl`  if we set the  bool `taggedOutput` as true but if we set it to false the result is returned on  the text        `TextOutput` without problems so how can i resolve this problem

the code:

```
P4Command command = new P4Command(ps, "diff2", false, new String[] { "-ds", depotpathleft, depotpathright });
Perforce.P4.Options op= new Options();
op.Add("-u","");
P4CommandResult result= command.Run(op);
TaggedObjectList list = (result.TaggedOutput);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known behavior of the 'diff2' command. You might raise this concern with Perforce Technical Support so that they can notify you if this behavior is changed in the future.

For the time being, I think your only option is to run the command with untagged output.

Comment: thank you i want to ask you about the result what is the meaning of this result                                                       add 3 chunks 28 lines
deleted 0 chunks 0 lines
changed 2 chunks 4 / 12 lines